# Ignore errors within expect

Tags: ansible

I am doing a build which by default returns Build Failed. This is the desired output but it interrupts the playbook execution.

I tried adding `ignore_errors` after the command but it's not letting me do that as it's not a valid parameter for expect.

```
- name: Do a build.
  expect:
    command: build
    responses:
      'Password\:': ''
```

I expect it to pass a password when asked for one, ignore the build failed message that appears and then do ahead with the rest of the steps. Is anyone able to help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`ignore_errors` is a task parameter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-failed-commands), not an `expect` module parameter. Just a guess from your question: you didn't use the correct indentation.

The following is wrong

```
# Will error with unknown parameter for module expect
- name: Do a build.
  expect:
    command: build
    responses:
      'Password\:': ''
    ignore_errors: true
```

This should work:

```
- name: Do a build.
  expect:
    command: build
    responses:
      'Password\:': ''
  ignore_errors: true
```

Don't forget that spaces and indentation are significant in yaml. Take a few minutes to review a [fast reading lighten spec](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/yaml/)

Comment: ahhh I see, I thought that ignore_errors was supposed to go right after command, like the first example you've shown. Thanks a lot!